# Для чего нужен reserve() в C++?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, vector, stl

Не могу понять, в чем смысл функции `reserve()`. Она выделяет память, но не создает элементов, увеличивает емкость, но не размер. Для чего она нужна если все можно сделать с помощью `resize()`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Для оптимизации. `resize` требует инициализации всех элементов, и делает размер контейнера строго заказанным. Он становится заполненным чем-то - что вам может быть не нужно в данный момент. При этом вам придется отслеживать отдельно реальную заполненность вашего вектора, т.к. `size()` будет, по сути, врать - говоря, сколько всего элементов в векторе, а не элементов, нужных вам. Если же вы хотите добавлять с помощью `resize()` равно столько элементов, сколько вам в данный момент нужно - то это просто бестолку потраченное время на инициализацию и не более того... потому что каждый вызов будет вызывать перераспределение памяти и копирование.

`reserve` подготавливает место для последующего заполнения, так что какой-нибудь `push_back` будет гарантированно (а не амортизированно) выполняться за O(1) - без каких-либо перераспределений памяти, съедающих массу времени... При этом `size()` будет давать точное количество элементов, итератор `end()` показывать куда надо...

Примерно так. Если не убедил - могу еще немного поубеждать :)

Comment: То есть, если мне нужно сделать несколько пушбэков, то сначала имеет смысл зарезервировать память? А resize() выходит есть смысл использовать только тогда, когда нам необходимо уменьшить количество элементов в векторе?

Comment: Если только несколько - обычно смысла не имеет. Как не имеет смысла резервировать 5-10-20 элементов. Вектор обычно выделяет (зависит от реализации) новый объем памяти с запасом (скажем, по заполнении удваивает его). А вот если данных будет реально много, а сами данные - большого размера, или требуют копирования большого объема памяти - тогда да, это имеет смысл.