# Вылезает ошибка при обращении к vector вне main

Tags: c++, vector

Вот код:

```
#inclue <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector< vector<int> > g;
vector<char> used;

void dfs(int v)
{
    used[v] = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < g[v].size(); i++)
    {
        if(!used[g[v][i]]) dfs[g[v][i]];
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n, k;
    cin >> n >> k;
    g.reserve(n);
    used.reserve(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        g[i].reserve(n);
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            int v;
            cin >> v;
            g[i].push_back(v);//ошибка вылазит тут
        }
    }
    dfs(k-1);

    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(used[i]) c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

текст ошибки:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Answer (score 1):

Очевидный вылет за пределы вектора `g`. Ваш вектор `g` имеет размер 0, а вы смело лезете в `g[i]`.

Количество доступных элементов вектора задается методом `resize`, а не методом `reserve`.

См. также [Для чего нужен reserve() в C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756287/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-reserve-%D0%B2-c)

Comment: Ок. Но почему если бы я объявил этот вектор в main(), то ошибка бы не вылезла?

Comment: @MatveyKiselyov Вылезла бы, конечно. Но в общем ваш код имеет неопределенное поведение и что в нем "вылезло" или "не вылезло" большого значения не имеет. Кстати, а как именно вы его объявляли в main?